# library path for Tcl extension in C

Tags: c, tcl, tk-toolkit

I use `Tcl_CreateObjCommand` to build a Tcl extension in C called libA.so, the C code call the function from an external C library called libext.so,  where should I put libext.so, so that the tcl could find and load it when it load libA.so

Comment: Where are you getting libext.so? Is it something you build or obtain elsewhere?

Comment: it's a library I build

Comment: Hm. It appears there's no good place to put libext.so (apart from the standard place like /usr/lib). If you cannot, either (1) put it somewhere in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (not an ideal solution) or (2) put it somewhere at a known place and have Tcl package code `dlopen` it before it loads libA.so (you can use the dlopen tcl extension for that).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a package installer

If you have a package manager you should install tcl/tk with it.

`sudo apt-get install tk`

or you might want also `tk-dev` (which is sometimes called `tk-devel`):

`sudo apt-get install tk tk-dev`

#### Install manually

- You **can** put so's manually in /usr/local (libraraies in /usr/local/lib/ and include files in /usr/local/include/), But remember to avoid installing them under `/usr` if you **do** have a packaging system.
- There's also an option of putting them under your project directory, but you'll have to help the [dynamic linker](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) find them (using LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ld.so.conf). Also, you'll have to update your project's include paths and library paths.